# How Do I Get Vagrant/Puppet To Add Linux Passwords Correctly?

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I am trying to use Vagrant to create an Ubuntu VM. My host is Windows7 and my basebox is precise64.
If I do the recommended way of adding a user in Puppet like this:

```
    user { "johnboy":
    ensure => present,
    managehome => true,
    password => '$6$ev8faya2$M2pB3YQRpKUJMnJx6LnsyTbDdi.umsEEZttD01pk8ZSfMGrVmlnjoVhIHyuqYt3.yaG1SZjaoSxB39nNgFKb//',
    groups => ["admin"],
    shell => "/bin/bash";
 }
```

I log in after vagrant has provisioned my box and the hash is not in /etc/passwd.

If I don't set it with the resource type but use exec and usermod like this

```
user { "johnboy":
    ensure => present,
    managehome => true,
    groups => ["admin"],
    shell => "/bin/bash";
}

exec { 'set password':
    command => "usermod -p '$6$ev8faya2$M2pB3YQRpKUJMnJx6LnsyTbDdi.umsEEZttD01pk8ZSfMGrVmlnjoVhIHyuqYt3.yaG1SZjaoSxB39nNgFKb//' johnboy",
    require => User[johnboy];
}
```

I end up with only part of the hash in /etc/passwd

```
johnboy:.umsEEZttD01pk8ZSfMGrVmlnjoVhIHyuqYt3.yaG1SZjaoSxB39nNgFKb//:16101:0:99999:7:::
```

Some pages suggest installing ruby-shadow so I tried this:

```
gem install ruby-shadow
```

However, the install failed, probably because I don't have Ruby installed. Vagrant was a 100 MB download. Is the gem for managing passwords really not included with that?

How do I get Vagrant/Puppet to provision the password correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it's stored inside the /etc/shadow file. This is for security reasons as it is only accessible by the root/super user.

Escape the dollar signs in the hash like this and it should work.

```
exec { 'set password':
    command => "usermod -p '\$6\$ev8faya2\$M2pB3YQRpKUJMnJx6LnsyTbDdi.umsEEZttD01pk8ZSfMGrVmlnjoVhIHyuqYt3.yaG1SZjaoSxB39nNgFKb//' johnboy",
    require => User[johnboy];
}
```

Comment: Vagrant provisions as root doesn't it? That doesn't explain how when I put in the hash and run usermod only half of it goes in /etc/passwd either.

Comment: Escape the $ sign in the password like \$, this is needed because you wrapped the command in double quotes and so variable interpolation is allowed